# Clear cookies programmatically in Cordova + Angular

Tags: angularjs, cordova, cookies

When I close my mobile app, all the session variables are gone.  I'm trying to do the same in my app's logout function.  I've tried suggestions found here; Phonegap-Cookies-Plugin nor angular-cookies returned any cookies when I queried for them.  Watching the network traffic in Chrome I see that a cookie named JSESSIONID is sent in the request but I can't find where in $http to clear this cookie.

Comment: if that cookie is created server side need to cancel it server side

Comment: but then how is it cleared when I exit the app (i.e. settings->apps->force close)?